# Is it possible for Http Session Invalidation to occur because of an overload on the Server?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, cpu-usage, httpsession

I have reaccuring random Invalidations of User Http Sessions resulting
in loss of temporary data on an Oracle IAS 10.1.2 
with Oracle Container for Java J2EE Container. (Java 1.4)

- Framework is Spring 2.5.
- Invalidation occuring with 2 concurrent Users.

Multiple tests could not reproduce the error so far.

I was wondering if it is possible that Session Invalidation
might be caused by CPU overload or by reaching the maximum
allowed number of threads on the server.

Comment: I've never seen this. But I've also never used "Oracle Container for Java J2EE Container".

Comment: Is there a way to find out the cause of a session invalidation? I have implemented session listeners, but I do not know what to look for.

Comment: I've worked on OC4J webapps with hundreds of concurrent users. If you're having a problem with just 2 it's not OC4J's fault.

Comment: As to finding the invalidation cause: Add the line `Thread.dumpStack();` to `sessionDestroyed()` method to get the call stack (so that you can learn what exactly called it). My initial suspicion is however that you assigned the `HttpSession` as a static variable or as an instance variable of some application wide class and thus got shared/overridden among multiple users. But that would have been a pretty stupid/obvious mistake with desastreus consequences on a production environment.

Comment: The httpSession is injected with some login Information. Appart from that Spring is handling Session Beans which I access/modify through the ApplicationContext. I will gather more information through dumpStack - thank you for your suggestions!